# Elixir: Nested If Statements

Tags: elixir, nested-if

I have this simple piece of code that would be very straightforward in most languages. I'm really struggling to see how to do this. How would I convert this into Elixir without getting the dreaded variable unsafe warning?

```
dc = 1
sd = 5
sdi = 6
calc = 1
bc = 1
dd = 10

if (dc == 1) 
    csd = sd
    bd = sd   
    p = sdi  

    if (calc == 1 && bc != 1) do
        count = 1
    else
        count = 20
    end       

else
    csd = dd  
    bd = dd  
    p = dd 

    count = 1
end
```

Comment: it works for me. Just add a `do` after the first `if`: `if (dc == 1) do`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also the answer by @Dogbert is perfectly valid, I would go with pattern matching all the way:

```
{csd, bd, p, count} = case {dc, calc, bc} do
 {1, 1, 1} -> {sd, sd, sdi, 20}
 {1, 1, _} -> {sd, sd, sdi, 1}
 {1, _, _} -> {sd, sd, sdi, 20}
 {_, _, _} -> {dd, dd, dd, 1}
end
```

In my opinion, it is more straightforward (plus I hate to use `if` in functional languages.)

Comment: Thank you. I like your answer and it works great. It's a very clever solution and very compact. IMHO I don't think it is as readable as the original nested if code above. I must be getting old. :-(

Comment: Honestly, I never was able to read `if`s, specifically nested `if`s :) I believe it’s a matter of habit. I am 42, btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tuples and pattern matching:

```
dc = 1
sd = 5
sdi = 6
calc = 1
bc = 1
dd = 10

{csd, bd, p, count} = if dc == 1 do
  {sd, sd, sdi, if(calc == 1 && bc != 1, do: 1, else: 20)}
else
  {dd, dd, dd, 1}
end

IO.inspect {csd, bd, p, count}
```

Output:

```
{5, 5, 6, 20}
```

I would also extract that `if` to a separate variable if it becomes too long to put on a single line with others:

```
new_count = if(calc == 1 && bc != 1, do: 1, else: 20)
{sd, sd, sdi, new_count}
```

Comment: Don’t you hate `if`s as I do hate ’em? :) Please see my answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa yup, that's nice! I wanted to make minimal changes to show how the warnings could be eliminated but I would most likely use a solution like yours in my projects (although in this case it seems like it's causing a lot of repetition of `{sd, sd, sdi` so I might stick with `if` in this exact situation).

Comment: One might remove first two clauses and use `if` in the third one as: `{1, _, _} -> {sd, sd, sdi, if(calc == 1 && bc != 1, do: 1, else: 20)}`, it’s still more idiomatic, than nested `if`s.